# Network (graph/nodes) visualization in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graph

Hi I'm pretty brand new to React Native (and have never used React JS) and it has been a nightmare looking for stuff with React and React Native being indistinguishable in a search lol.

So far I've found this which has worked, but is pretty lack luster in terms of design: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-graph

I really want to use something like this: https://github.com/crubier/react-graph-vis or maybe https://github.com/danielcaldas/react-d3-graph, but I'm not sure if it's even possible, or if there are is a good way of searching for React Native components.

Comment: amazing community

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as Matt Takao, so I created [react-native-vis-network](https://github.com/High5Apps/react-native-vis-network#readme).

It's just a thin wrapper around [vis-network](https://github.com/visjs/vis-network#readme) and [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview#readme), but it works well for my use case. I know this is 3 years too late, but hopefully it helps others.